# Activate a Macro each time I use a Validation List in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Validation List that selects different countries. Each country has different sellers and I have to make a Validation list for them too. The problem is that I have to run a macro manually (with a button) each time I select a different country. I want the macro to run/activate each time I use the country validation list and not manually(button).

I don't think any of the code I'm using is needed to solve my problem. I'll post the last part anyway.

```
Dim strFormula1 As String

strFormula1 = "=$z$1:" & Worksheets("graficos").Range("z1").End(xlDown).Address()


With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=strFormula1
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call the macro inside the **Worksheet_Change** event handler in the worksheet class module.

On the worksheet tab at the bottom, right-click and choose *View Code*. This opens the VB Editor, showing the code pane of the Worksheet.

In there, select **Worksheet** from the objects drop-down at top-left, and **Change** from the events drop-down at top-right.

In the event-handler, paste the code to call your macro

Comment: Yup `Worksheet_Change` is the way too go :)

Comment: But how do I specifically select the change in the validation list (it's on range("b3")) and not any change on the worksheet. I must be doing something wrong because when I use the list it seems to go into a loop. I had to stop the macro because it never ended. Sorry but I forgot to say I'm new to macros.

Comment: maybe you could try `if target.address<>"B3" then exit sub` at the top of the *Worksheet_Change* event handler which will check the changed cell is the one with the validation. then after that you can put your code to kick off the other macro

Comment: Sorry but I'm still stuck here, do I have to define the range for target? When I do what you tell me I automatically get this: 
`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` or `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` if I use change.

Comment: you should use *Change* so you get `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. **Target** is passed in by Excel, and this will be the range that is changed in the worksheet

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is relevant for you but could you use the INDIRECT formula to create validation lists that return results depending on the selection in box 1 rather than using a macro? Eg:

List 1 contains England, Scotland, Wales and Ireland

Make 4 further lists called England, Scotland, Wales and Ireland and in each list put the relevant options for each country. Name each range as England, Scotland etc...

Then create new data validation lists with the source as =INDIRECT(England) =INDIRECT(Scotland) etc..

Apologies if this isn't very clear. I have included an example below for a car bodyshop where they choose from the TYPE list first and the 2nd list changes dependant on what is selected in type. All bold items are names of ranges

**TYPE**
?
Alloy
Bumper
Panel
Texture
Interior

**ALLOY**
?
N/S/F
N/S/R
O/S/F
O/S/R

**BUMPER**
?
N/S/F Corner
O/S/F Corner
N/S/F Insert
O/S/F Insert
Front Centre
Full Front
N/S/R Corner
O/S/R Corner
N/S/R Insert
O/S/R Insert
Rear Centre
Full Rear

**PANEL**
?
N/S Wing
N/S/F Door
N/S/R Door
N/S Quarter
N/S Roof Rail
N/S Sill
N/S Mirror Cap
N/S/F Door Handle
N/S/R Door Handle
N/S/F Door Moulding
N/S/R Door Moulding
O/S Wing
O/S/F Door
O/S/R Door
O/S Quarter
O/S Roof Rail
O/S Sill
O/S Mirror Cap
O/S/F Door Handle
O/S/R Door Handle
O/S/F Door Moulding
O/S/R Door Moulding
Bonnet
Tailgate
Roof
Full Polish

**TEXTURES**
?
N/S/F Bumper Corner
O/S/F Bumper Corner
N/S/F Bumper Insert
O/S/F Bumper Insert
Front Bumper Centre
Full Front Bumper
N/S/R Bumper Corner
O/S/R Bumper Corner
N/S/R Bumper Insert
O/S/R Bumper Insert
Rear Bumper Centre
Full Rear Bumper
N/S Mirror Cap
N/S Moulding
O/S Mirror Cap
O/S Moulding

**INTERIOR**
?
N/S/F Seat
O/S/F Seat
N/S/R Seat
O/S/R Seat
N/S/F Carpet
O/S/F Carpet
N/S/R Carpet
O/S/R Carpet
Dashboard
Screen Chip